# Error changing ownership using subprocess and icacls in Python on Windows

Tags: python

I'm trying to change file ownership on Windows using Python's subprocess module and the icacls command-line tool. However, when I execute the code, I encounter the following error:

```
Error changing ownership of C:/Windows/addins: Command '['icacls', 'C:/Windows/addins', '/setowner', 'lenovo']' returned non-zero exit status 6.
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import subprocess
import os

def change_file_ownership(path, username):
    try:
        subprocess.run(['icacls', path, '/setowner', username], check=True)
        print(f"Changed ownership of {path} to {username}")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error changing ownership of {path}: {str(e)}")

file_path = 'C:/Windows/addins'
new_user = os.getlogin()

change_file_ownership(file_path, new_user)
```

I have verified that I am running the script with administrative privileges. The file path and the username are correctly provided. However, I cannot figure out why I am getting this error. Could someone please help me understand the issue and provide guidance on how to resolve it?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Add argument `capture_output=True` to `run`, set `check=False`, store the returned `CompletedProcess` object in a variable and print its `stdout` and `stderr`.